# Why is a URL alias messing up my view's contextual filter?

Tags: views, nodes, path-aliases

I'm having an issue configuring a URL alias that redirects content to a view with a contextual filter.

**Here's my working setup:**

1. I have a bunch of content of type SEEL Lesson Plan.
2. To display these lessons in a Library, I created a view with the path http://example.com/seel/
3. I set up a contextual filter (Content: Title) on the view. So, if you access http://example.com/seel/eat-an-apple, it will display the lesson with title "Eat an Apple" in the Library.

**Here's my objective:**

I want to override the "Save" button, so when clients edit any content of type SEEL Lesson Plan, it takes them to the library (http://example.com/seel/eat-an-apple) rather than the content page (http://example.com/content/eat-an-apple).

*How do I do that?*

---

**Here's what doesn't work:**

I added the following URL alias at http://example.com/admin/config/search/path/patterns:

[image]

I created a new content of type SEEL Lesson Plan that uses this URL alias. I can see it in my list of URL aliases (http://example.com/admin/config/search/path/list/seel):

[image]

But, when I go to http://example.com/seel/fdsa to test it out, it totally messes up. I'd include a screenshot if I could, but the HTML elements are literally all over the place -- displaying below the block on the left sidebar instead of in the main content pane, floating all over the footer, etc.

**Here's how I know it's a problem with URL aliases:**

When I go back and delete the URL alias [seel/fdsa](http://seel/fdsa), and then go to http://example.com/seel/fdsa, it displays exactly how I set it up originally in the view.

As well: other lesson plans, for which there is no URL alias, display just fine. (For example: http://example.com/seel/eat-an-apple still works.)

*Why is this happening?*

Comment: You have two conflicting routes - seel/* for the node, and seel/* for the View (the View will normally "win" in my experience)...couldn't say why that manifests itself as a broken layout without more info I think, but having two routes with the same pattern is likely to end with weirdness. You mentioned that the content page should be at http://example.com/content/eat-an-apple, so why add the pathauto alias as well? The node won't be available from the /content path once you've done that

Comment: And to answer your first question, "How do I do that?", you can take the (a) Site-Building approach: Use the Rules module, or (b) Programmatic approach: Use a custom Form API submit handler function, where you set the  `$form_state['redirect'] = SOME_DESTINATION;`.

Comment: @Clive I don't want it to be available from the content/* URL, only through the view.

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis Is (b) essentially the same as using .htaccess to set up a 301?

Comment: You should set up a redirect then, yes. Currently Drupal is getting confused because you're trying to jam 2 things into a single path. A and B are the same thing by the way, just accomplished with different approaches

Answer (score 0):

At @Clive's suggestion, I ditched the idea of trying to do this with URL aliases, and instead set up a redirect with the Rules module.

This was done by going to [/admin/config/workflow/rules](http:///admin/config/workflow/rules), clicking "Add New Rule", and reacting on event "Content is viewed".

The final rule looks like this:

[image]

And it works :-)